# Group by week in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query with output like this

```
7   2017-05-02 00:00:00.000
96  2017-05-15 00:00:00.000
79  2017-05-16 00:00:00.000
310 2017-05-17 00:00:00.000
76  2017-05-18 00:00:00.000
83  2017-05-19 00:00:00.000
```

I want to group them by weeks.

ideal output being

```
7     Week 1
644   Week 2
```

Any help on how to group like this will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using ?

Comment: @prdp I'm using MSSQL - SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can live with the databases definition of a week:

```
select datename(year, datecol) + '-' + datename(week, datecol) as yyyyw,
       sum(col) as sumcol
from t
group by datename(year, datecol) + '-' + datename(week, datecol)
order by min(datecol);
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what i was hoping to get.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

**Example**

```
Select SomeValue = sum(SomeValue)
      ,WeekNr=concat('Week ',dense_rank() over (Order By datepart(week,SomeDate)) )
 from YourTable
 Group By year(SomeDate),datepart(week,SomeDate)
```

**Returns**

```
SomeValue   WeekNr
7           Week 1
644         Week 2
```